# Where do you report serious flaws with iOS7?

Tags: ios, bug

I now have a list of over twenty serious flaws with iOS7. It is driving me nuts that this new iOS is so riddles with flaws it should never have been released in this state, and Steve Jobs wouldn't have permitted it so. And this site just helped me resolve the mystery of why all my contacts vanished this morning. (thank you!) when the iOS decided to suddenly and for no apparent reason turn off contact syncing sometime overnight. I've hesitated to do a blog post as I'm sure no one at Apple would read my blog though it is a high trafficked blog in my market and would certainly hurt Apple sales, which isn't my desire, I'm a mac fan boy - but frustrated with all the problems and it seeming like after 4 updates, they aren't fixing them.

Thanks! I'd happy list them here if this is the place. If not, just delete this post. But I'd like to be helpful and note a complainer, but at a dead end on how/where to post up to 25 critical flaws that are hindering the practical use of the iPhone now. (despite the fact I still prefer it over the other options)

How do you get Apple to hear and address these things?

Comment: I would also put them in your blog, so that others (assuming they duplicate your experience) can chime in with apple for fixes, as it usually takes a lot of that to generate action.  What is your URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding iOS at Apple's feedback page relevant for the device that you wish to feedback for:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html
- http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html
- http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipodtouch.html

If you are an Apple Developer, you can report bugs using [Apple Bug Reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/using-bug-reporter/).